# C++ boost split without using is_any_of()

Tags: c++, boost

This below function will produce output as {"a","b","c"} as vector for the string input "a=b+c" when delimiter is "+="

```
void Split( const std::string &str, std::vector<std::string> & tokens , std::string delim)
{
     boost::split(tokens, str, boost::is_any_of(delim));
}
```

I need output as {"a=b+c"}
Please suggest for modifications or any suitable functions available

Comment: Well, if you just want that output on that input, `tokens = {str};`. Somehow I doubt that's what you actually want.

Comment: It is just an example, boost::is_any_of() is splitting based on multiple delimiter(characters of string). I need something that takes entire string as delimiter

Comment: Your question is still not clear. If you treat `a=b+c` as the *delimiter*, then the result should be empty, because the input is split based on the delimiter, and the remaining parts are returned. The delimiter itself is not returned. You may want [`find_all`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/algorithm/find_all.html) instead of `split` if you're searching for all occurrences of a substring.

Comment: `"a=b+c"` is input string where `"+="` is delimiter, as delimiter is not present in input it should produce output as `"a=b+c"` but it is considering + or = as delimiter and splitting based on them

Comment: So what the OP trying to say is that they dont want '+=' to be two separate delimiters '+' and '=', they want the code to search for the combination of '+=' and if it doesn't find both of those characters next to each other return the original string. @Praetorian

Answer (score 1):

This is the code you're looking for, regular `split` only takes chars so you have to use `split_regex` instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string str = "a=b+c" ;
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    boost::algorithm::split_regex(result, str, boost::regex("\\+="));
}
```

Note you'll have to link it to `boost_regex` with `-lboost_regex` otherwise it'll fire errors at you.

Also in the string `"\\+="` the reason why there are two backslashes is that regular expressions use `'+'` as a special character so then you have to use a `'\'` character to escape that usage, but one `'\'` turns it into a special character `'\+'` so you must escape the first `'\'` like so: `'\\+='`

Comment: @akash-h Can you tell me if this code worked for you?